# Making a timer in C# - Seconds to minutes to hours etc

Tags: c#, math, timer

I am trying to make a timer in C#. I do this by counting frames then making a variable(seconds) that is equal to the number of frames divided by 60. I also count minutes by having another variable(minutes) that is equal to seconds divided by 60.

***The problem***
When minutes is upped by one, seconds keeps counting and i am not sure how to fix this. I want to add one to minutes whenever seconds reaches 60 but then go back down to zero without seting minutes to zero.

Here is what I've tried:

```
    int frames = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
```

***This is in update:***

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        minutes = seconds / 60;

        seconds = frames / 60;

        frames += 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you *just* count frames, and derive seconds and minutes from that, whenever you need to. So if you really need to update all the variables in each `Update` call, you'd have:

```
frames++;
seconds = (frames / 60) % 60;
minutes = frames / (60 * 60);
```

Or to be clearer, define some constants:

const int FramesPerSecond = 60;
   const int SecondsPerMinute = 60;
   const int FramesPerMinute = FramesPerSecond * SecondsPerMinute;

...

```
frames++;
seconds = (frames / FramesPerSecond) % SecondsPerMinute;
minutes = frames / FramesPerMinute;
```

(If you need to reset minutes to 0 after an hour, you would need to extend this further.)

It's not clear what you're trying to do though - there may well be a better way of achieving it. If you're definitely trying to count frames, this is fine... but if you're trying to compute elapsed time, you should remember a base time and then subtract that from the current time, rather than relying on a timer firing *exactly* once per second.

Comment: I know this is a basic question, but:
"seconds = frames ***%*** 60"
what does "%" mean?

Comment: @SethTaddiken: It's the remainder operator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx (That page incorrectly calls it the modulus operator, but ignore that part. It really *is* the remainder operator :)

Comment: @SethTaddiken: 0 in both cases, as there's no remainder. A better example would be `5%3`, which is 2 - because 5 divided by 3 is 1, with a remainder of 2.

Comment: i think its counting in milliseconds?

Comment: @SethTaddiken: If it's counting in milliseconds, then you'd need to divide by 1000. Given your original code, I was assuming your `Update` method was being called once per second. Rereading your question, if it's 60 frames per second, you do indeed need to divide by 60. Will edit.

Comment: @SethTaddiken: I've edited my answer - but your general context is still unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions as to how to write a good question.

Comment: i am trying to create a timer that counts seconds and minutes. I am stuck on how to do that.

Comment: @SethTaddiken: But where do frames come in? What is `GameTime`? Is this meant to reflect *real* elapsed time? If so, you should be using the system clock... There are *lots* of details missing here.

Comment: I have a variable, "frames", that gets 1 added to it every update. I divide the number of frames by 60 to get seconds because there are 60 frames per second

Comment: @SethTaddiken: No, I know nothing about 3D graphics, and that's irrelevant to this question. If you have a new question, you should ask it *in* a new question. I still suspect that assuming you will always get exactly 60 frames per second may not be a good idea.

Comment: OK. So do you mean that there probably aren't 60 frames per second?
If so, should I use the timer that C# has? (I don't really know what it is or how to use it)

Comment: I'm saying that depending on how the frames are being allocated (we *still* have no idea, as you *still* haven't provided enough context - which you should do in your question, rather than in comments) you may sometimes get 59 or 61 frames, for example. Maybe using frames is good enough for you at the moment - as you appear to be a beginner in C#, it may be the most appropriate way to go for the minute.

Comment: is there a timer that C# already has that i could figure out and use?

Answer (score 2):

Attention: If you count from 0 to 60 (for minutes and second) you count 61 seconds. So go from 0 to 59 in your conditions.

for example there are 5 fingers at a hand but if we count from 0 we have 6 finger. (are we mutand?)

:)

Answer (score 1):

So, if you don't need System.Threading.Timer or System.Threading.DispatcherTimer, you can just use standard TimeSpan and add miliseconds to it. 
Or create your own TimeSpan-like class with automatically incrementing properties.